# Password Policies do not Work When There is a User Federation

Tags: java, keycloak

I have build an custom user storage provider using this [example](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-user-storage-provider-demo/tree/master/jar-module/src/main/java/de/tdlabs/keycoak/ext/storage/demo).

Unfortunately when you activate this user federation then password policies do not work. For example under Authentication → Password Policy → Add policy… → Minimum Length. This does not work. Is there any workaround to activate password policies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may call the password policies check yourself in method `updateCredential()` of yor custom *UserStorageProvider*.

Use this code snippet:

```
PasswordPolicyManagerProvider pwPolicyManager = session.getProvider(PasswordPolicyManagerProvider.class);
PolicyError err = pwPolicyManager.validate(user.getUsername(), cred.getValue());
if (err != null) {
  // log error here
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I've uısed this one `PolicyError error = session.getProvider(PasswordPolicyManagerProvider.class).validate(realm, user, cred.getValue());`.